# Simplyfing a quotient of polynomials

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions

I am trying to simplify some quotient of polynomials. In this case, they are really easy but I will have to deal with way harder expression and I wanna know how to do it in full generality. An example is

This is just

\begin{equation}
(z_1-z_2)^{-h-2}\left(\frac{(z_1-z_2)(z_3-z_4)}{(z_1-z_3)(z_2-z_4)}\right)^{2+h}\left(\frac{z_1-z_4}{z_1-z_3}\right)^{2-h}\left(\frac{z_2-z_4}{z_1-z_4}\right)^{2-h}(z_3-z_4)^{-2-h}
\end{equation}

```
Simplify[(z1 - z2)^(-2-h) ( (((z1 - z2) (z3 - z4))/((z1 - z3) (z2 - z4)))^(2 
+ h)) ((z1 - z4)/(z1 - z3))^(2 - h) ((z2 - z4)/(z1 - z4))^(2 - h) (z3 - z4)^(-2 - h)]
```

This should just simplify to $
\frac{1}{(z_2-z_4)^{2h}}\frac{1}{(z_1-z_3)^{4}}$.
I understand that Mathematica is afraid and don't want to simplify everything, even if given the fact that h is an integer. Is there someone that know what to do to get the final simplification ?

Comment: Use `PowerExpand[]`.

Comment: @ J.M. is somewhat okay, Thank you very much